# Occupied RAM without process

Tags: c#, .net, memory, memory-leaks

Solved. It had nothing to do with my application closing but drivers which locked up to 1.2 GB RAM.

When my application is closing then the memory gets released (overall RAM usage sinks). Sometimes after this, the overall RAM usage of the machine rises with no apparent reason. This is pretty much random. Perhaps once out of 20 times trying.

About my Application:

It's a WPF-Application with EntityFramework for the database access and SQL-Dependency for refreshing data.

Aboutthe OS:

The OS witch delivers this behavior is Windows Server 2012 R2 (terminalserver with Citrix). I couldn't reproduce this on Windows 7 or Windows 8.1.

Until now I worked under the assumption when my Application dies, the whole memory will be freed. Does anybody have an idea what could cause this?

Edit1:
The Terminal Server I tested it on, was isolated for Testing. The only running applications were taskmanger and my application perhaps an Explorer. Even Logout didn't free the Memory allways.

Edit2:
The network specialist who came to me with this problem analysed it further from his end. He went over every process on this machine (which did nothing else but test my programm) and added the memory use together. He was off more than 1 GB. I think he should have seen all processes and services. But I will ask him about it.

I'll be more than gratefull if it is something from the OS. I just need to make sure its not a bug.

@Those who downvote:

 I do realise it is a difficult question to answer, since all memory should be released on closing. I can't give very much details on how to reproduce this not because I don't want to find it out but because 2 days of searching didn't give much. It just pops up once in a while.

Comment: It could be something different than applications only, take a look at the services on the Terminal Server. Your application should release all resources when closed.

Comment: Really you a sure that nothing else could have been running on that machine.  No way it was doing some maintenance task like indexing, apply update ....  You have no evidence the WPF did not free memory.  Why are you tagging the wpf and memory-leaks

Comment: Your Server has an operating System, which uses lots of programs behind the scenes. You are just reading the wrong statistics.  
Did you take a look into resource monitoring?

Answer (score 0):

If your application is closed it cannot allocate memory anymore. If you look at overall memory utilisation, then some *other* process is responsible for that, not yours. Keep in mind that the operating system has plenty of parts and runs plenty of applications. It's not just your own application there.

Especially in a Terminal Server environment the applications you're running contend for the same resources as everyone else on the server. If someone else starts an application you can expect to see memory usage rise.

Comment: Thats what I'd expect. Unfortunately the Server I tested it on was only for testing and we knew who had which applications open. It seems to be Memory no Process behind it.

Comment: You do realise that drivers and services can use memory too?

Comment: And Windows can use it for caching.

Comment: @Lasse: That usually doesn't show up in the used portion.